# A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type email to be controlled in react

Tags: reactjs

```
index.js:1375 Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type email to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: 
in input (at userModal.js:57)
in div (at userModal.js:56)
in div (at userModal.js:55)
in div (at userModal.js:49)
in div (at userModal.js:47)
in form (at userModal.js:42)
in div (at userModal.js:41)
in div (at userModal.js:40)
in div (at userModal.js:39)
in div (at userModal.js:36)
in UserModal (created by ConnectFunction)
in ConnectFunction (at home.js:15)
in div (at home.js:12)
in div (at home.js:11)
in div (at home.js:10)
in Home (created by ConnectFunction)
in ConnectFunction (created by Context.Consumer)
in Route (at App.js:26)
in div (at Layout.jsx:20)
in Layout (created by ConnectFunction)
in ConnectFunction (at App.js:17)
in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
in BrowserRouter (at App.js:16)
in App (at src/index.js:30)
in Provider (at src/index.js:29)
```

console. @ index.js:1375**strong text***emphasized text*

**please explain this A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type email to be controlled**

Comment: Paste the component code please.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely means that the initial value of your input is undefined, then you start typing => that results in the value being set. Give the inputs value an initial state and it should resolve.

Answer (score 0):

It might mean that you don't have `onChange` callback but provided `value` attribute instead of `defaultValue`. So if that input should be controlled, provide `onChange` callback, if not - use `defaultValue` instead of `value`.